# How to use an action listener to check if a certain button was clicked?

Tags: java, button, actionlistener

I have 4 lists of buttons arranged into a column in my program. As of now I have 4 loops that check to see if a button has been clicked or not. Is there a simple way to check if any button has been clicked instead of looping through each list to see if that certain button was clicked. There must be an easier way to check if "actionSource == anybutton"...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use anonymous inner classes for each button:

```
JButton button = new JButton("Do Something");
button.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        System.out.println("Do Something Clicked");
    }
});
```

Or if your logic is related, then you can share a listener:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ButtonCalculator extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    private JButton[] buttons;
    private JTextField display;

    public ButtonCalculator()
    {
        display = new JTextField();
        display.setEditable( false );
        display.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setLayout( new GridLayout(0, 5) );
        buttons = new JButton[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)
        {
            String text = String.valueOf(i);
            JButton button = new JButton( text );
            button.addActionListener( this );
            button.setMnemonic( text.charAt(0) );
            buttons[i] = button;
            buttonPanel.add( button );
        }

        getContentPane().add(display, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        getContentPane().add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        setResizable( false );
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        JButton source = (JButton)e.getSource();
        display.replaceSelection( source.getActionCommand() );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        UIManager.put("Button.margin", new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10) );
        ButtonCalculator frame = new ButtonCalculator();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Camickr is a Swing authority in my eyes.

Comment: Share a listener... nice, thanks for the advice! That worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You can add an individual listener for each button and one common listener to every button.  Program the common listener to respond to "any button pressed".

Answer (score 0):

Any time you click a button, it triggers the `actionPerformed` method, regardless of which button you pressed.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    Object source = event.getSource();
    if (source instanceof JButton) System.out.println("You clicked a button!");
}
```

Comment: I still have other object with listeners on them, such as combo boxes and menu items. I need only the buttons to do a certain task, not all the items with a listener.