# Addition item in ArrayList during the course of the program

Tags: java, arraylist

I need to get into the method "createCircles" another item, after pressing the button. Because I draw circles by canvas, from this ArrayList. So I did the following. But when it runs, so when you press the button nothing happens. My question is, if it is properly registered my additional items to the box.

```
public class krouzky extends View {
    final Paint mMalovani;
    ArrayList<Circle> mCircles;

    private boolean KontrolerVykreslovani = true;

    public krouzky(Context context, AttributeSet atrs) {
        super(context, atrs);

        mMalovani = new Paint();
        mMalovani.setColor(Color.RED);
        mMalovani.setAntiAlias(true);

        createCircles();

    }

    private void createCircles() {
        mCircles = new ArrayList<Circle>();
        mCircles.add(new Circle(120, 30, 7));

    }

    public void Pridani_kruhu() {
        Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                createCircles(v);
            }
        });
    }      

    private void createCircles(View v) {
        mCircles.add(new Circle(120, 30, 15));
    }
```

If there's an item to add before the start of the program, a method looks like this, so he draws two circles according to plan.

```
private void createCircles() {
    mCircles = new ArrayList<Circle>();
    mCircles.add(new Circle(120, 30, 7));
    mCircles.add(new Circle(130, 30, 12));
}
```

Thank you for your advice

The complete actvivity is here.

```
public class krouzky extends View {

final Paint mMalovani;  


ArrayList<Circle> mCircles;

private boolean KontrolerVykreslovani = true;

public krouzky(Context context, AttributeSet atrs) {
    super(context, atrs);

    mMalovani = new Paint();
    mMalovani.setColor(Color.RED);
    mMalovani.setAntiAlias(true);

    createCircles();
}

private void createCircles() {
    mCircles = new ArrayList<Circle>();

    mCircles.add(new Circle(120, 30, 7));
}



public void Pridani_kruhu() {

    Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            createCircles(v);
        }
    });
    }          

private void createCircles(View v) {    
    mCircles.add(new Circle(120, 30, 15));
}


public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    // pokud je mDrawinEnabled "true" tak udělá .....
    if ( KontrolerVykreslovani ) {
        //přiřazení hodnot do proměnných width a height
        final int width = canvas.getWidth();
        final int height = canvas.getHeight();

        kresleníKruhu(canvas);



        invalidate();
    }
}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();

    Circle cr = findCircleClosestToTouchEvent(x, y);



    float dtcr = euclidDist(cr.getCurrentX(), cr.getCurrentY(), x, y);

        handleTouchedCircle(event, cr);

    return true;
}

private void kresleníKruhu(Canvas canvas) {
    for (Circle c : mCircles) {

        canvas.drawCircle(c.getCurrentX(), c.getCurrentY(), c.getRadius(),
                mMalovani);
    }
}



private static float euclidDist(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2) {
    return android.util.FloatMath.sqrt((x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1) + (y2 - y1)
            * (y2 - y1));
}


private Circle findCircleClosestToTouchEvent(float x, float y) {

    Circle c = mCircles.get(0);

    float dist = euclidDist(c.getCurrentX(), c.getCurrentY(), x, y);        
    float tempdist = 0;
    for (Circle cr : mCircles) {
        tempdist = euclidDist(cr.getCurrentX(), cr.getCurrentY(), x, y);
        if (tempdist < dist) {
            c = cr;
            dist = tempdist;
        }
    }
    return c;
}

private void handleTouchedCircle(MotionEvent me, Circle c) {

    final float me_x = me.getX();
    final float me_y = me.getY();
    final int action = me.getAction();

    switch (action) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        c.setActionDownX(c.getCurrentX());
        c.setActionDownY(c.getCurrentY());
        c.setActionMoveOffsetX(me_x);
        c.setActionMoveOffsetY(me_y);
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        c.setCurrentX(c.getActionDownX() + me_x - c.getActionMoveOffsetX());
        c.setCurrentY(c.getActionDownY() + me_y - c.getActionMoveOffsetY());
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        c.restoreStartPosition();
        break;
    }
}


final void MuzemeVykreslovat() { KontrolerVykreslovani = true; }

final void NemuzemeVykreslovat() { KontrolerVykreslovani = false; }
```

}

Comment: You are adding to the ArrayList correctly. However, you pass a View to createCircles() but you do nothing with it. Also, you do not show us what a View is. At some point you'd have to draw the circles. I don't see you actually drawing circles anywhere. You have this Paint object but don't seem to use it. I think you need to post more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void createCircles() {
    mCircles = new ArrayList<Circle>();

    mCircles.add(new Circle(120, 30, 7));
}
```

This Creates a new `ArrayList<Circle>` every time it is called, writing over whatever circles it has. If you mean to instantiate the ArrayList instead of wipe it, try this:

private void createCircles() {
    if (mCircles == null) { mCircles = new ArrayList(); }

```
mCircles.add(new Circle(120, 30, 7));
```

}

This should instantiate the ArrayList whenever it is null only.

Also, if you are testing this by looking at the GUI of this, the circles may be stacking. This means that it maybe making the circles just fine but at the same time, not showing them, because they all have the properties of `(120, 30, 7)`. Consider placing them randomly, or in set different locations with different properties so that you know that they aren't stacking.

Comment: I did it like this, but the result is same. Every circle shoud be visible, because all circles are moveable.

Comment: Is your button in the JPanel or whatever you are drawing to? Also, have you tested your Button's functionality? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300135/java-action-listener That has more of the type of ActionListener that I'm used to, but you may be using something that I'm unfamiliar with (its been a while since I have done non J2EE GUI work)

Comment: Yes, my button is OK. I tested with toast text. (thenks for your tip)