# Simple Calculator with all buttons created and actions added in JButton array

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

### I'm self learning java beginner

i'm trying to create simple calculator using java swing and i want to create array of JButtons to create all the buttons in the project , i had some issues so i declare all variables outside the constructor

```
public class SimpleCalculator extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
JButton btnArray[] = new JButton[16];
JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel("Ghanayem's Calculator",
        SwingConstants.CENTER);
JTextField txt = new JTextField();
JPanel numPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 3, 15, 5));
JPanel opPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 1, 0, 5));
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1, 0, 5));
int counter;
char operation;
double operand1;
double operand2;
```

like that ,and i think to add actions to buttons inside for-loop no compiler errors every thing is ok

```
for (counter = 0; counter < 10; counter++) {

        btnArray[counter] = new JButton("" + counter);
        btnArray[counter].addActionListener(this);
    }
```

and here is action performed implementation

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    txt.setText(txt.getText() + counter);
}
```

just like that ,when i try to run the program and press any number button the number added to text field is "16" for all buttons, and this is main method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                SimpleCalculator frame = new SimpleCalculator();
                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setResizable(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

i am getting crazy i don't know what is wrong , please i need your help this my first swing application i am so disperate

thank you

Comment: Words typed in all lower case are hard to read, like trying to listen to someone who is mumbling.  Please use an upper case letter at the start of sentences, for the word I, and proper names like `ArrayList` or Oracle.

Comment: I will do next time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JButton b = (JButton) e.getSource();
    txt.replaceSelection(b.getActionCommand());

}
```

this is a solution for my question i found here 
[java-action-listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300135/java-action-listener)

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String value = (JButton) e.getSource().getText();
    txt.setText(txt.getText() + value);

}
```

and this is another solution @Paco Abato helps me to find

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this (I can't test right now so it may contain some lesser errors):

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String value = ((JButton)e.getSource()).getText();
    Integer intValue = Integer.parseInt(value);
    Integer intValue2 = Integer.parseInt(txt.getText());
    txt.setText( "" + (intValue + intValue2));
}
```

Comment: thanks ,i tried your answer and the only wrong thing that setText method needs String you pass it integers

so i edit your solution like that

`String value = ((JButton)e.getSource()).getText();
     txt.setText(txt.getText() + value);`

and guess what .. it works

i also find another solution i will add it to next answer

i couldn't sleep until i found the answer ,so thanks for help

Comment: Ups, I edit my answer. You can accept it if solved your issue.

Comment: Be aware that `txt.getText() + value` will not add two numbers, instead it will concatenate two strings. `"2" + "5"` results in 25 not 7.

Comment: i knew that , but putting intValue and intValue2 in parentheses will make + sign is addition sign not concatenation sign ,if you  remove parentheses , your answer will be right