# Send text from text field to list

Tags: java

I want write text in my text Field and when i select on button my string go to list. But i don't know what do i do?

This is my code: I'm new member in programmers world and my age is 15 please help.

```
package com.company;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Jframe extends JFrame {

private String list23 = "";
private JButton button1;
private JPanel panel1;
private JTextField textField1;
//public JList list1;
private JButton Button2;
private JList<String> list1;
public Jframe(){


setContentPane(panel1);
panel1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
pack();
setSize(555,555);       


button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


        String text = textField1.getText();
        System.out.println(text);

    }
});
```

Comment: For a **15**-year old - almost OK.  You forgot to put your executable code inside a method.  When you click a button and after you add a new item to your list, what (if anything) should happen to your text field?

Comment: And, of course, you will need to add your components to the frame (or its content pane).

Answer (score 0):

`list1.add(text);` will add the `text` String to your `list1`. Just link this code to an action listener for a button press and you should be good.

Hopefully that helps

Comment: You need an action listener to watch for a button to be clicked, and then specify what you want to happen once that button is clicked (in this case, add the text to the list). You can read about them here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300135/java-action-listene

Comment: Please i need do this.i don't know what should i do.pls

Comment: What are you trying to do? I do not what to just give you a block of code as an answer, it is better learning to figure it out. I will answer questions though so ask away

Comment: i rote this code and i got error in my text between list.add(text);

Comment: String text = textField1.getText();
                list1.add();

Comment: i have red underline under my text string in the list.add(text); why?

Comment: When you try to run it your compiler will tell you the error. It will probably give you a line number and the data type it is expecting and the data type it is getting. Use these to try to find where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

You did almost fine. But currently you are not adding the text from the textfield to the list. Just do it as:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    list1.add(textField1.getText());  //add text to list
}
```

Also remember to initialize your variables before you use them, else you are going to get a `NullPointerException`.

- If you are using ArrayList (which seems to be what you want), you can use `.add()`.
- If you indeed want to use JList. You need to add through the listModel:
  `listModel.addElement()`.

Comment: i got red underline error  under (textField1.getText()); why?

Comment: @kingramx Your compiler will tell you why, that is an error. By the way, are you sure you want to use JList and not an ArrayList?

Comment: can yo make an example?

Comment: Where can i use from list model?

Comment: @kingramx This is not how this site works. We will answer specific question, but it is not a replacement to learn the basics. My advice is, learn from the basics (including how to use an IDE)

Comment: And what do i need?

Comment: please make example that has all my codes .i don't ask more questions.

Comment: `List<String> list1 = new ArrayList();` instead of your `JList`.

Comment: Sorry but i can not understand .i will go to another site.thanks for your help.